# How to find polygon area in google map using latlang

Tags: android, location

I am working on google map application,i want to find the area of irregular polygon with 4 markers,i have latitude and longitude of 4 points i want to find polygon area between points,please reply

code:

```
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    count++;
    if (count <= 4) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(latLng.toString()));
        markerClicked = false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    if (markerClicked) {
        if (polygon != null) {
            polygon.remove();
            polygon = null;
        }

        polygonOptions.add(marker.getPosition());
        polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#cc0000"));
        polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.parseColor("#332256"));
        polygon = mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
    } else {
        if (polygon != null) {
            polygon.remove();
            polygon = null;
        }

        polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().add(marker.getPosition());
        markerClicked = true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/): [computeArea](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeArea-java.util.List-).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) library , [here](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/classGeographicLib_1_1PolygonAreaT.html) documentation about computing polygon area by points.